# Change the levels of a factor in all the columns of a variable in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to change the level of factors in each column in a more efficient way (iterative or a generic script). Columns are to be modified to have levels 1 to r where is the # of levels in that factor.

Currently, I am modifying them by writing command for each column:

```
setattr(lizards$Diameter,"levels",c(1,2))
setattr(lizards$Species,"levels",c(1,2))
setattr(lizards$Height,"levels",c(1,2))

str(lizards)
lizards         409 obs. of 3 variables
 Species : Factor w/ 2 levels "Sagrei","Distichus": 1 1...
 Diameter: Factor w/ 2 levels "narrow","wide": 1 1 1 1 ...
 Height : Factor w/ 2 levels "high","low": 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

Comment: use `mapply` if levels are different

Comment: `lizards[] <- lapply(lizards, factor, labels="")` even

Comment: Thanks for the input. It worked!!

Comment: @thelatemail I tried NULL for labels, one of these days I'm going to one up you but not today